# Luigi write file directly to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, luigi

I'm creating a data pipeline with Luigi and I'm trying to write the processed data to S3 bucket directly. The code I used is:

```
import luigi
from luigi.s3 import S3Target, S3Client

class myTask(luigi.Task):
    def requires(self):
        return otherTask()

    def output(self):
        client = S3Client('ACCESS_KEY', 'SECRET_KEY')
        return S3Target('s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myfolder/myfile.tsv', client=client)

    def run(self):
         fo = self.output().open('w')
         with self.input().open('r') as f:
            data = dosomething_to_input(f)
            fo.write(data)
         fo.close()
```

After I run the script, I got Error:

```
S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Can we directly write file into S3 bucket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved!
It's because of the format of the s3 buckt.
The correct format should be 's3://mybucket/myfile'
The 405 ERROR is caused by boto not recognizing the bucket name.
Also need to mention that boto does not recognize bucket name with '.' in it in Python 2.7.*, so you have to use a valid bucket name or change it in the config file.